# Why do we use linear interpolation in the contruction of Brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I am familiar with Lévy's construction of Brownian motion as the limit of linear interpolations of gaussian values. But could we define a stochastic process in one shot as
$$ B_t := \sum_{\mathcal{D} \ni d<t} 2^{-(|d|+1)}Z_d, $$
Where $\mathcal{D} $ are the dyadic numbers and index a family of iid. standard normal gaussians, and $|d|$ is the length of the dyadic expansion of $d$, and then show that $B$ is a Brownian motion ? I feel like this formula could work, because the variances at $t$ sum to $t$, but I'm not sure how to proceed for a proof. I think I'd need some kind of result that the series of Gaussian RVs is again Gaussian, which I'm not sure about.

Comment: There are many ways to construct Brownian motion.  Perhaps this is one of them.  Have you tried showing it satisfies the definition of a Brownian motion?

Comment: I guess the main reason is to deal with the issue of the sample space on which processes are defined. Due to measurability concerns, one has to start with a sample space $\Omega$ on which 'events about continuous functions' are measurable. A popular choice for $\Omega$ is the space of continuous functions, and this is probably why many elementary construction sticks to continuous sample paths. RCLL (càdlàg) functions are perfectly fine if $\Omega$ is chosen as a Skorokhod space, although this requires more works.